# How do I test controller as syntax with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor, angularjs-controlleras

I'm currently writing some Protractor tests for an app. But in the app i'm using controller as syntax as the pieces I want to work on are components. The problem is that when i use the selector of "" $ctrl.functionName"" it's giving me an illegal selector statement.

Anyone have any ideas about this?

```
let btn = $$("button[ng-click^=$ctrl.initRequest].secondary.bf-btn");
        expect(btn.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

The error message is

```
Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Comment: Please share Code.

Comment: Why don't you assign a semantic ID or class to your button instead of relying on low-level implementation details to select it? The test shouldn't have to care about controller vs. controllerAs. It should find the button identified by "init-request" (for example), and test whether it's displayed or not.

Comment: I think we'll have to do that from now on a lot of features on the application haven't been given strict ID's. Must mail the people working on it to start putting id's onto buttons and elements.

Comment: @JBNizet is right. In addition to it not working, if you couple your tests to internals like that they will break constantly. Maintenance nightmare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot assign a meaningful `id` or other attribute to the element, you need to fix your current selector. At the very least, there should be quotes around the `ng-click` value:

```
button[ng-click^='$ctrl.initRequest'].secondary.bf-btn
```

Note that a slightly better version, that would also not require quotes, would be to use a partial match:

```
button[ng-click*=initRequest].secondary.bf-btn
```

And, see if you can drop the questionable classes and have just:

```
button[ng-click*=initRequest]
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks very much! rest of the team are now under instruction for ID's everywhere!